# Select from database and display in combobox-GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, jcombobox

I'm trying to select the names of the items from the database and then save it into an array to later add it to the JComboBox but for some reason it's not taking it from the database at all.

Here's the part of the code which is supposed to do that:

```
public BirthdayForm()
{
    super("Birthday Party Supplies Rental Form");
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/";
    String dbName = "partySupplies";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String username = "root";
    String pw = "";
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,username,pw);


    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    String[] list = null;
    chooseItem = new JLabel("Choose Item:");
    String selectSQL = "SELECT productName FROM birthday where productName = ?";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
    ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL );
    while (rs.next()) {
        String name = rs.getString(2);  
        System.out.println(name);
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        list[i] = name;
        }
    }
    items = new JComboBox(list);

    chooseQuantity = new JLabel("Choose Quantity:");
    quantity = new JTextField("1");
    choose = new JPanel();
    choose.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
    choose.add(chooseItem);
    choose.add(items);
    choose.add(chooseQuantity);
    choose.add(quantity);
    add(choose);

//other codes
```

Comment: Your code appears to combine GUI code with database code, making it hard for you and us to know where your problem lies. You would be wise to try to "divide and conquer", meaning to break this class down into smaller classes, each with its own responsibilities, and then debug your problem in your smaller classes, such as a database only class. This way if you still have problems, you can post an entire functioning but small class for us to inspect, test and modify.

Comment: The problem is that i'm new with GUI and therefore i didn't know how to link the database class with the GUI part therefore i merged both. :/

Comment: That's not a good plan. Again, you need to be able to test these guys in isolation. You can give your database class methods that any other class, be it a GUI or not, can call, that would allow extraction of data from it.

Comment: You're right i'll try to do so in the future thanks. For now can't you just tell me how i can display the array in the combobox please?

Comment: Just have a look at the [JComboBox API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) and you'll see that it has a constructor that takes an array. If you want to enter data into the combo box after it has been created, the API will also show you the `addItem(...)` method.

Comment: @Damini might be your list is null,even after DB part . Try to add print statement for list before 'items = new JComboBox(list);' and check list have some value or not

Comment: i agree with all of the above - using database algorithms within the **constructor** of a **UI class** is the worst thing imaginable. I think you need to do learn some basic programming things first. Its necessary - in any other case you will either fail or produce something very horrible; i dont want to offend any newcomer but thats reality ... sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select it like this from your database.

```
combobox.addItem(rs.getString("items"));
```

It takes the "items" from your resultset and it puts it into a String and it adds it to your combobox.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Strings to a JComboBox like this:

```
String item1 = "This is my first item";
String item2 = "This is my second item";

combo.addItem(item1);
combo.addItem(item2);
```

In the end it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I wanted to take from the database to add it to the JComboBox.